# Do figures need to be in a sensible order?

Tags: drafting, patent-figures

Is it strictly necessary to arrange figures in a sensible order? Or can I simply append drawings to the end as I think of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that they need to be in sensible order but I suggest that you do present the claims in sensible order to help the examiner to better understand your invention.

From the manual of patent examination procedures:

http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s608.html

Not intended as legal advice.

Please mark this answered if you are satisfied.